# Restore deleted docker container in Virtual Machine

Tags: docker, container

I have connected to a VM via SSH in Visual Studio Code and in that connected to docker container. When I closed the container, the container got deleted permanently.
When I check in VM "docker ps" , it is not showing the container ID.

Please help to restore the container

Answer (score 3):

Try running `docker ps -a` - this show all containers - including stopped ones.

If it's there, just run: `docker start <container-name>`

If it's not on the list, then you didn't just stop it, but instead removed it completely. In this case, the container have to be created again.

Hopefully, you have set up [persistent storage](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for your containers.